# Link custom header in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-headers

I am trying to achieve the basic function of using a custom header on my home page in Wordpress.

I am only just learning wordpress but I will try and explain.

So I have both a parent and child theme, the parent theme has a folder called 'inc' with a file custom-header.php ready to tailor.

I have duplicated the 'inc' folder and placed it in my child theme folder.

At the top of page.php file in the parent folder (there is no duplicate in the child folder) I have changed

```
get_header(); ?>
```

to

```
get_header(custom-header); ?>
```

I have tried making dramatic changes in both the Parent custom-header.php and the duplicate child custom-header.php and nothing happens.

I have also tried changing the file names, for example header-home.php and then calling

```
get_header("home"); ?>
```

and this does not work either.

I have put the get_header in the top of the page.php as I think this is where it is served from (with my limited knowledge) and when I try and edit it, the page fails to reload, so I would assume it is the right php file but I am obviously doing something wrong. I have spent quite some time looking but it is suprisingly difficult to get a clear, concise explanation on the right syntax and exactly where I place the get_header code and actually keep the custom header file.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

The only correct versions you used was:

```
//file: header-home.php

get_header('home');
```

Unfortunately for header files, they need to be in the root directory of your active theme (or parent theme if using a child) to be called. i.e. `themes/custom-theme/header-home.php`

You are correct as in you change the `get_header()` function in your page files, but dont forget your home page may be `front-page.php`, `home.php`, `index.php` or a `page-whatever.php` if using a wp page as the front page.